# How could call powershell script in c# with parameters

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to invoke powershell script with parameters from c#. Is there any option to give just powershell script file along with parameters rather than giving whole powershell command as a string in c# code.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C) article and/or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527513/execute-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-with-commandline-arguments) previous SO question could help you? (**PS.** because you specified C# in your question I've removed the VB.NET tag)

Comment: I trying to get some common method for .net framework, not specific for  c#

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick google search really gives you all you need. This one is from http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/42716

You'll need the Reference `System.Management.Automation`
then use

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
```

Create a runspace to host the PowerScript environment:

```
Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runSpace.Open();
```

Using the runspace, create a new pipeline for your cmdlets:

```
Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline();
```

Create Command objects to represent the cmdlet(s) you want to execute and add them to the pipeline. This example retrieves all the processes and then sorts them by their memory usage.

```
Command getProcess = new Command("Get-Process");
Command sort = new Command("Sort-Object");
sort.Parameters.Add("Property", "VM"); 
pipeline.Commands.Add(getProcess);
pipeline.Commands.Add(sort);
```

The preceding code functions identically to the following PowerShell command line:

`PS > Get-Process | Sort-Object -Property VM`

Finally, execute the commands in the pipeline and do something with the output:

```
Collection output = pipeline.Invoke();
foreach (PSObject psObject in output)
{
  Process process = (Process)psObject.BaseObject;
  Console.WriteLine("Process name: " + process.ProcessName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made it some thing like this last

```
public static string RunScript(string scriptText)
    {
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);
        pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
        try
        {
            Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
            runspace.Close();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            if (pipeline.Error.Count > 0)
            {
                //iterate over Error PipeLine until end
                while (!pipeline.Error.EndOfPipeline)
                {
                    //read one PSObject off the pipeline
                    var value = pipeline.Error.Read() as PSObject;
                    if (value != null)
                    {
                        //get the ErrorRecord
                        var r = value.BaseObject as ErrorRecord;
                        if (r != null)
                        {
                            //build whatever kind of message your want
                            stringBuilder.AppendLine(r.InvocationInfo.MyCommand.Name + " : " + r.Exception.Message);
                            stringBuilder.AppendLine(r.InvocationInfo.PositionMessage);
                            stringBuilder.AppendLine(string.Format("+ CategoryInfo: {0}", r.CategoryInfo));
                            stringBuilder.AppendLine(
                            string.Format("+ FullyQualifiedErrorId: {0}", r.FullyQualifiedErrorId));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(string.Format("Build is Success"));
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string err = ex.ToString();
            err = "Build Failed!!!" + "\r\n" + "Check the Setup File Available or Path error";
            return err;
        }
    }


 SCRIPT = "buildmsi.ps1 " + ssource + " " + sdestination;
            projectbuildstatus.Text = RunScript(SCRIPT);
```

Thanks Ale Tiro for idea