# How to pass arguments to a powershell script from C# program?

Tags: c#, powershell, parameter-passing

I have a script file sample.ps1 which has the following command :

```
copy-item C:\source -destination C:\destination.
```

Instead of hard coding the value for source and destination I want to pass it as arguments to the script.

```
copy-item $source -destination $destination.
```

I want to call this script from a stand alone client and pass the source and destination as parameters.
I have the following program to execute the script file :

```
            string shellUri = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell";
            string userName = "MachineName\\Administrator";
            string password = "Password";
            SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();

            foreach (char c in password)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }
            PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(userName, securePassword);
            WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(false, "machinename", 5985, "/wsman", shellUri, credential);
            using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
            {

                runspace.Open();
        String file = "C:\\scripts\\Sample.ps1";
                Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

                pipeline.Commands.AddScript(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file));
        }
```

I want to pass the parameters to the script Sample.ps1 through the C# program. How is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the answers to all of your questions:

- [Execute PowerShell Script from C# with Commandline Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/527644/3107178)
- [Invoking PowerShell Script with Arguments from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10260767/3107178)
- [How could call powershell script in c# with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15763352/3107178)
- [Passing parameters to powershell script in C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/80ecaa29-c209-4256-9359-ff0c39ce43f9/passing-parameters-to-powershell-script-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading the file and using `Commands.AddScript` to inject its contents **as text**, I'd rather use the `Commands.Add` method to add a command that would **call the Sample.ps1** script directly, as a file:

```
pipeline.Commands.Add( "C:\\dirWithNoSpaces\\scripts\\Sample.ps1 -param1 value1");
```

but be careful about escaping.. I've just read that if there any spaces in the path, it has to be quoted:

```
pipeline.Commands.Add( "&\"C:\\dir with spaces\\scripts\\Sample.ps1\" -param1 value1");
```

However, if you'd like to keep it as you have it now, you might look for some ways to add 'parameters' in Pipeline or Runspace objects. For example, I've just found this: [Runspace.InitialSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace.initialsessionstate.aspx) - you inject some initial variables to the runtime environment, so you could use it to pass values to inlined-scripts. However, the values will already be in-variables, not in the ARGV or such.

Comment: FYI: I have not tried it. I'm basing on [this question](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0c8b4d50-e87c-48f6-807c-f338a32103fc/powershell-pass-connection-string-as-a-parameter-for-a-script). It should work, but still I just guess.

Comment: I tried the above method without parameter, but I am getting the following error : 'Unhandled Exception: System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: The term 'C:\scripts\Sample.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, scrip
t file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.'