# C# - Remove Exchange Email Address via Powershell Runspace

Tags: c#, powershell, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

Per [Technet - Add or Remove Email Addresses for a Mailbox](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123794%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx), using the PowerShell console, the following successfully removes an email alias from a mailbox :

```
Set-Mailbox "GenMgr" -EmailAddresses @{remove="GenMgr@domain.com"}
```

However, invoking the PSCommand object below via remote runspace throws a System.Management.Automation.RemoteException error.

```
command.AddCommand("Set-Mailbox");
command.AddParameter("Identity", "GenMgr");
command.AddParameter("EmailAddresses", "@{remove='GenMgr@domain.com'}");
powershell.Commands = command;
powershell.Invoke();
```

System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'EmailAddresses'. Cannot convert value "@{remove='GenMgr@domain.com'}" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ProxyAddressCollection". Error: "The address '@{remove='GenMgr@domain.com'}' is invalid: "@{remove='GenMgr@domain.com'}" isn't a valid SMTP address. The domain name can't contain spaces and it has to have a prefix and a suffix, such as example.com."

It seems to me the problem is with the 'remove' instruction in the EmailAddresses parameter.

How do I use C# and the PowerShell remote runspace on Windows 8 to get Exchange 2010 to remove an email alias?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Powershell uses the [`@{ key = value }` syntax](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/10/15/automatically-create-a-powershell-hash-table-10-15-11.aspx) to create a [hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx).  Instead of passing a string, pass the hashtable with a single `remove` element with the value of `email@address.com`.

See the related question [Passing a hashtable from C# to powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18839268/138200) for more.

```
command.AddCommand("Set-Mailbox");
command.AddParameter("Identity", "GenMgr");

var addresses = new Hashtable();
addresses.Add("remove", "GenMgr@domain.com");
command.AddParameter("EmailAddresses", adresses);

powershell.Commands = command;
powershell.Invoke();
```

Comment: And to remove multiple aliases, use a string array for the value of the hashtable 'remove' entry.  Your example was spot on.