# UTF-8 output from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, io-redirection

I'm trying to use `Process.Start` with redirected I/O to call `PowerShell.exe` with a string, and to get the output back, all in [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). But I don't seem to be able to make this work.

What I've tried:

- Passing the command to run via the `-Command` parameter
- Writing the PowerShell script as a file to disk with UTF-8 encoding
- Writing the PowerShell script as a file to disk with UTF-8 with [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) encoding
- Writing the PowerShell script as a file to disk with UTF-16
- Setting `Console.OutputEncoding` in both my console application and in the PowerShell script
- Setting `$OutputEncoding` in PowerShell
- Setting `Process.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding`
- Doing it all with `Encoding.Unicode` instead of `Encoding.UTF8`

In every case, when I inspect the bytes I'm given, I get different values to my original string. I'd really love an explanation as to why this doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DumpBytes("Héllo");

    ExecuteCommand("PowerShell.exe", "-Command \"$OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8 ; Write-Output 'Héllo';\"",
        Environment.CurrentDirectory, DumpBytes, DumpBytes);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void DumpBytes(string text)
{
    Console.Write(text + " " + string.Join(",", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text).Select(b => b.ToString("X"))));
    Console.WriteLine();
}

static int ExecuteCommand(string executable, string arguments, string workingDirectory, Action<string> output, Action<string> error)
{
    try
    {
        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo.FileName = executable;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            process.StartInfo.StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            using (var outputWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
            using (var errorWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
            {
                process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.Data == null)
                    {
                        outputWaitHandle.Set();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        output(e.Data);
                    }
                };

                process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.Data == null)
                    {
                        errorWaitHandle.Set();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        error(e.Data);
                    }
                };

                process.Start();

                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                process.WaitForExit();
                outputWaitHandle.WaitOne();
                errorWaitHandle.WaitOne();

                return process.ExitCode;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Error when attempting to execute {0}: {1}", executable, ex.Message),
            ex);
    }
}
```

#### Update 1

I found that if I make this script:

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
Write-Host "Héllo!"
[Console]::WriteLine("Héllo")
```

Then invoke it via:

```
ExecuteCommand("PowerShell.exe", "-File C:\\Users\\Paul\\Desktop\\Foo.ps1",
  Environment.CurrentDirectory, DumpBytes, DumpBytes);
```

The first line is corrupted, but the second isn't:

```
H?llo! 48,EF,BF,BD,6C,6C,6F,21
Héllo 48,C3,A9,6C,6C,6F
```

This suggests to me that my redirection code is all working fine; when I use `Console.WriteLine` in PowerShell I get UTF-8 as I expect.

This means that PowerShell's `Write-Output` and `Write-Host` commands must be doing something different with the output, and not simply calling `Console.WriteLine`.

### Update 2

I've even tried the following to force the PowerShell console code page to UTF-8, but `Write-Host` and `Write-Output` continue to produce broken results while `[Console]::WriteLine` works.

```
$sig = @'
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetConsoleCP(uint wCodePageID);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetConsoleOutputCP(uint wCodePageID);
'@

$type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -Name Win32Utils -Namespace Foo -PassThru

$type::SetConsoleCP(65001)
$type::SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)

Write-Host "Héllo!"

& chcp    # Tells us 65001 (UTF-8) is being used
```

Comment: Why start `Powershell.exe` instead of using `System.Management.Automation` to [embed PowerShell right in the app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527513/execute-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-with-commandline-arguments)?

Comment: I had an, um, friend, who built an entire app on top of `System.Management.Automation`. But after the 765th complaint from users of "I have a script that works like this under PowerShell.exe but like that under your host" I, I mean my friend, decided to give up on the idea.

Comment: I posted some info here: https://octopusdeploy.com/blog/improving-powershell

Comment: I think you're over thinking this ... you just need to accept the fact that it's UTF-16 ;-)

Comment: Why do you say UTF-16? It seems to be the OEM codepage

Comment: "Writing the PowerShell script as a file to disk with UTF-8 with BOM encoding". This has solved my issue. I guess Powershell got it wrong already when reading the input without BOM.

Comment: Consider using `[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode()` in PS and `UrlDecode()` in C#.  Hopefully `$OutputEncoding` has been fixed in PS 7, but my code will need to work w/ PS 5 for a long time yet, and also be easily understood by other team members.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a bug in .NET. When PowerShell launches, it caches the output handle (Console.Out). The Encoding property of that text writer does not pick up the value StandardOutputEncoding property.

When you change it from within PowerShell, the Encoding property of the cached output writer returns the cached value, so the output is still encoded with the default encoding.

As a workaround, I would suggest not changing the encoding. It will be returned to you as a Unicode string, at which point you can manage the encoding yourself.

Caching example:

```
102 [C:\Users\leeholm]
>> $r1 = [Console]::Out

103 [C:\Users\leeholm]
>> $r1

Encoding                                          FormatProvider
--------                                          --------------
System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding                  en-US



104 [C:\Users\leeholm]
>> [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

105 [C:\Users\leeholm]
>> $r1

Encoding                                          FormatProvider
--------                                          --------------
System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding                  en-US
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Lee. What do you mean by "It will be returned to you as a Unicode string, at which point you can manage the encoding yourself.". I'm trying to call `Encoding.GetEncoding(850).GetBytes(textOutputByPowershell)`, followed by `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`, but this also seems to produce the wrong output.

Comment: It should be a .net string (thus, UTF16) already. Setting StandardOutputEncoding is never guaranteed to work anyway, because "setting this property does not guarantee that the process will use the specified encoding..."  Having said that, I think it defaults to your Windows CodePage :-/

Comment: Thanks everyone, got it working! (Solution added to original post)

Comment: What was your solution @PaulStovell ? I don't quite see it up above. Dealing with python code that writes to powershell's stdout, and going through cp1252 doesn't work so well when the source has unicode.

Answer (score 26):

Not an expert on encoding, but after reading these...

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/11/outputencoding-to-the-rescue.aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847796.aspx
- http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/08/25/powershell-output-redirection-unicode-or-ascii/

... it seems fairly clear that the $OutputEncoding variable only affects data piped to native applications.

If sending to a file from withing PowerShell, the encoding can be controlled by the `-encoding` parameter on the `out-file` cmdlet e.g.

```
write-output "hello" | out-file "enctest.txt" -encoding utf8
```

Nothing else you can do on the PowerShell front then, but the following post may well help you:.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ddietric/archive/2010/11/08/decoding-standard-output-and-standard-error-when-redirecting-to-a-gui-application.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Set the `[Console]::OuputEncoding` as encoding whatever you want, and print out with `[Console]::WriteLine`.

If powershell ouput method has a problem, then don't use it. It feels bit bad, but works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Spent some time working on a solution to my issue and thought it may be of interest. I ran into a problem trying to automate code generation using PowerShell 3.0 on Windows 8. The target IDE was the Keil compiler using MDK-ARM Essential Toolchain 5.24.1. A bit different from OP, as I am using PowerShell natively during the pre-build step. When I tried to #include the generated file, I received the error

> fatal error: UTF-16 (LE) byte order mark detected '..\GITVersion.h'
>   but encoding is not supported

I solved the problem by changing the line that generated the output file from:

```
out-file -FilePath GITVersion.h -InputObject $result
```

to:

```
out-file -FilePath GITVersion.h -Encoding ascii -InputObject $result
```