# Override Powershell > shortcut

Tags: powershell, encoding, utf-8

In Powershell using `>` is the same as using `| Out-File`, so I can write

`"something" > file.txt` and It will write 'something' into file.txt . This is what I expect of a shell. Unfortunately, Powershell uses Unicode for writing file.txt. The only way to change it into UTF-8 is to write the quite long command:

```
"something" | Out-File file.txt -Encoding UTF8
```

I want to override the `>` shortcut, so that it adds the UTF-8 encoding by default. Is there a way to do that?

NOT A DUPLICATE CLARIFICATION:

This is not a duplicate. As is explained clearly [here](https://superuser.com/questions/327492/default-powershell-to-emitting-utf-8-instead-of-utf-16), Out-File has a hard-coded default. I don't want to change Out-File's behavior, I want to change `>`'s behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 output from PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349139/utf-8-output-from-powershell)

Comment: No, it isn't. See clarification.

Comment: @zmbq according to the documentation, using `Out-File -Encoding` *is* the way to go, you cannot change the behavior of the redirection operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No, can't be done

Even the documentation alludes to this.
From the last paragraph of [`Get-Help about_Redirection`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx):

> When you are
> writing to files, **the redirection operators use Unicode encoding**. If
> the file has a  different encoding, the output might not be formatted
> correctly. **To redirect content to non-Unicode files, use the Out-File
> cmdlet with its Encoding parameter.**

*(emphasis added)*

Answer (score 1):

The output encoding can be overriden by [changing the `$OutputEncoding` variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/11/outputencoding-to-the-rescue.aspx). However, that only works for piping output into executables. It doesn't work for redirection operators. If you need a specific encoding for file output you must use `Out-File` or `Set-Content` with the `-Encoding` parameter (or a `StreamWriter`).