# How to configure the encoding for Powershell console?

Tags: powershell

I have some problems with displaying Chinese characters in the Powershell console. All Chinese are shown as rectangles there. I believe this is an encoding problem. Does anyone know how to configure the Powershell console to use UTF8 encoding?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349139/utf-8-output-from-powershell)

Current Encoding: `[Console]::Out`

Set Encoding (UTF8): `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8`

Comment: It seems we have to configure it for every PowerShell instance. Can we set the UTF8 encoding as default?

Comment: You can put it in the PS profile, which is loaded upon instance start.

Comment: That makes language specific characters just disappear from the output i.e. instead of ' ŻÓŁTY ' there is just ' TY '. Is there a way to fix this?