Oh-My-Posh Powershell random characters in promt
I am using Powershell 7.4.4 in Windows Terminal on Windows 10 and trying to set up Oh-My-Posh. I am using a nerd font (Lilex).  Other than using a different font, I have followed the setup procedure in the Oh-My-Posh docs exactly. I even went back and tried using the reccomended font and it has the same problem.
When I run oh-my-posh init powershell | Invoke-Expression I get characters that are rendered just fine, but the appear to be random unicode characters as if the mapping is off or something.
Image of issue
After running the oh-my-posh init powershell | Invoke-Expression command I am expecting a prompt interface that looks something like this:
enter image description here

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573209/how-to-configure-the-encoding-for-powershell-console

To anyone else who ends up here - @jdweng was correct.  I had miss-understood the documentation in the FAQ talking about this.  Powershell 7 does already use UTF-8 (kind of), but there is some bug in recent (7.4) versions.  There was no image of what this issue looks like, so I thought it was referring to something else. There is an ongoing bug report with MS to try to fix this in Powershell.
