# Write strings with mixed encoding to console [Python]

Tags: python, encoding, output

Suppose I have a list of 4 songs (basically, in real life I don't know how many songs I have and how are they encoded):

1. OST Ходячий замок Хаула – Вальс "Карусель жизни"
2. Fäaschtbänkler – 22 Genres
3. Röyksopp – Running to the Sea (feat. Susanne Sundfor)
4. Omega – GyöngyhajúLány

**These songs contain**

1. Russian letters
2. ö, ä, ú

And this is example is far not the worst from what you might find in other cases

Basically, I need one encoding to rule them all, which one do I choose or how do I make it work in an other way?

**UPD:**
**Here is what I found on the site with this music**

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
```

**Solution**

I solved it by downloading [win_unicode_console](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console)
Still don't know how to do that in native python

Comment: What's you system, what's the current encoding in your console, what are the supported encodings of your console? What encoding do you use for Python strings? Do you use unicode or byte string? How on earth can we guess anything of that?!

Answer (score 0):

Use `utf8` encoding. to write to stdout using utf8, use:

```
utf8stdout = open(1, mode='w', encoding='utf8',errors='replace', closefd=False)
print("something", file=utf8stdout)
```

Comment: output.encode('utf8', 'replace') should work as well, shouldn't it?

Comment: @DenisRozimovschii `str.encode` functions are for changing them to bytes, if that is what you want, yes it would work

Comment: I want a normal string in the output.
And I have checked your answer. I get "╨е╨╛╨┤╤П╤З╨╕╨╣ ╨╖╨░╨╝╨╛╨║ ╨е╨░╤Г╨╗╨░ - ╨Т╨░╨╗╤М╤Б "╨Ъ╨░╤А╤Г╤Б╨╡╨╗╤М ╨╢╨╕╨╖╨╜╨╕" instead of the song name writter in russian

Comment: @DenisRozimovschii That might be your console`s problem

Comment: Replacing my code bits you yours - I get the wrong output for the song №1 listed in the question.

Comment: @DenisRozimovschii maybe your console doesn't support utf8. can you change your console's encoding?

Comment: I'm running an untouched Windows PowerShell

Comment: Windows console (cmd) returns the same output

Comment: @DenisRozimovschii type `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` in the powershell and try again?

Comment: @DenisRozimovschii see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349139/utf-8-output-from-powershell

Comment: It gives a different output, but it is not correct as well

Comment: @DenisRozimovschii In windows CMD, change the console font to Lucida and then type `chcp 65001`. Windows consoles doesn\t support utf8 by default, so it has problems with russian, etc.