# Execute PowerShell Script of flie from C# with Commandline Arguments

Tags: c#, powershell, command-line, scripting, arguments

I try to launch ps1 with parameter files from a c# program. But before this, I try to do it smaller, and run a "ls ." but it don't work, and I think that my code is OK.

```
pipeline.Commands.Add("ls ."); //in future here path of .ps1 file + arguments
Collection<PSObject> results;
// Execute PowerShell script
results = pipeline.Invoke();
//print it in a textbox
AppendLine(results.ToString());
```

I use like a reference [Execute PowerShell Script from C# with Commandline Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527513/execute-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-with-commandline-arguments)

the error is "System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: 'ls .' is not a cmdlet, function or bat file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression `ls .` consists of a command (or rather, an alias) `ls` *and* a parameter argument `.`

The proper way to construct that expression would be:

```
Command lsCmd = new Command("ls");
lsCmd.Parameters.Add("Path",".");
Pipeline.Commands.Add(lsCmd);
```

Comment: I' going to check like good the answer. But this only resolve partially my problem. Because in a .ps1 script I have the problem to split it to catch the command, and parameters. But you give me a great idea

Comment: Use an editor with syntax high-lighting (such as the free PowerShell ISE) to get an idea of how different tokens in your scripts are interpreted.