# Invoking a Powershell script in c#

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint, timer-jobs

I am new to scripting. I created a ps1 file that I want to deploy to Sharepoint Central Admin to create a Timer Job. I created a Timer Job script using C#, how can I go about calling the ps1 file within my C# program? How would I execute my script Ex: C:\MyItems.ps1?

Comment: you tried this ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527513/execute-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-with-commandline-arguments

Comment: should be tons of previous questions on this

Comment: `Process.Start("C:\MyItems.ps1");`