# Using C# to execute Powershell command (azureVM)

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to develop a .Net form application to manage azure VMs in C# using Powershell cmdlets. I'll have to use the Azure module to get this working.

One of the cmdlet will be Add-AzureAccount

My question is how can I include this module (Azure) in C# project ?

Comment: You will have to create a PS script and invoke it from C#. Refer to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread?

Comment: I just posted the answert @TomSun-MSFT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the comment section, @Prageeth Saravanan gave a useful link on how integrate PowerShell in C#.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/

**Quick example :**

First I had to include these refs :

```
System.Management.Automation
System.Collections.ObjectModel
```

**Note :** You need to add a NuGet package for  "Management.Automation". Just type "System.Management.Automation" you'll find it.

**C# code:**

```
//The first step is to create a new instance of the PowerShell class
using (PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create()) //PowerShell.Create() creates an empty PowerShell pipeline for us to use for execution.
{   
 // use "AddScript" to add the contents of a script file to the end of the execution pipeline.
 // use "AddCommand" to add individual commands/cmdlets to the end of the execution pipeline.

    powerShellInstance.AddScript("param($param1) $d = get-date; $s = 'test string value'; $d; $s; $param1; get-service");

    // use "AddParameter" to add a single parameter to the last command/script on the pipeline.
    powerShellInstance.AddParameter("param1", "parameter 1 value!");

    //Result of the script with Invoke()
    Collection<PSObject> result = powerShellInstance.Invoke();

    //output example : @{yourProperty=value; yourProperty1=value1; yourProperty2=StoppedDeallocated; PowerState=Stopped; OperationStatus=OK}}

    foreach (PSObject r in result)
    {
        //access to values
        string r1 = r.Properties["yourProperty"].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

We could  use PowerShell cmdlets [Import-module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module) to add corresponding modules to the current session.  We could use force parameter to re-import a module into the same session.
`Import-module -name azure -force`

The import thing is that  the imported module need to be installed on the local computer or a remote computer. So if we want to execute Azure PowerShell cmdlets from  C# project that we need to make sure that Azure PowerShell are installed. We can use install-module AzureRM  or Azure  more details please refer to the [Get Started Azure PowerShell cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azureps-cmdlets-docs/). In the Azure VM, Azure PowerShell is installed by default. 
About how to call PowerShell command or PS1 file using C# please refer to Prageeth Saravanan  mentioned [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/) or another [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527513/execute-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-with-commandline-arguments?answertab=active#tab-top).