# running powershell script with parameters with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, powershell

i have a powershell script that i want to kick off with vb.net code, however when it gets to the part where i invoke the pipeline i get the error "Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: District County FMS."
the powershell script is very simple, it takes 3 parameters and write-host's the param values back to the shell. pretty much my question is, how do i make it work? thank you everyone for you time.

vb.net(the other professionals i work with have boiled the error down to 'get-process' not being the right command for my scriptParams variable, but we're not sure which command to use)

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine(RunScript(LoadScript(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/CreateProject.ps1 ")))
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
Private Function RunScript(ByVal scriptText As String) As String

    ' create Powershell runspace 
    Dim MyRunSpace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()

    ' open it 
    MyRunSpace.Open()

    ' create a pipeline and feed it the script text 
    Dim MyPipeline As Pipeline = MyRunSpace.CreatePipeline()

    MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText)

    ' add an extra command to transform the script output objects into nicely formatted strings 
    ' remove this line to get the actual objects that the script returns. For example, the script 
    ' "Get-Process" returns a collection of System.Diagnostics.Process instances. 
    MyPipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String")

    '[ay]create a command object by bassing the command to the constructor
    Dim scriptParams As New Command("get-process")
    '[ay]pass parameters to the command
    scriptParams.Parameters.Add("District", "D1")
    scriptParams.Parameters.Add("County", "Lee")
    scriptParams.Parameters.Add("FMS", "101000")
    MyPipeline.Commands.Add(scriptParams)

    ' execute the script 
    Dim results As Collection(Of PSObject) = MyPipeline.Invoke()

    ' close the runspace 
    MyRunSpace.Close()

    ' convert the script result into a single string 
    Dim MyStringBuilder As New StringBuilder()

    For Each obj As PSObject In results
        MyStringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString())
    Next

    ' return the results of the script that has 
    ' now been converted to text 
    Return MyStringBuilder.ToString()

End Function

Private Function LoadScript(ByVal filename As String) As String

    Try

        ' Create an instance of StreamReader to read from our file. 
        ' The using statement also closes the StreamReader. 
        Dim sr As New StreamReader(filename)

        ' use a string builder to get all our lines from the file 
        Dim fileContents As New StringBuilder()

        ' string to hold the current line 
        Dim curLine As String = ""

        ' loop through our file and read each line into our 
        ' stringbuilder as we go along 
        Do
            ' read each line and MAKE SURE YOU ADD BACK THE 
            ' LINEFEED THAT IT THE ReadLine() METHOD STRIPS OFF 
            curLine = sr.ReadLine()
            fileContents.Append(curLine + vbCrLf)
        Loop Until curLine Is Nothing

        ' close our reader now that we are done 
        sr.Close()

        ' call RunScript and pass in our file contents 
        ' converted to a string 
        Return fileContents.ToString()

    Catch e As Exception
        ' Let the user know what went wrong. 
        Dim errorText As String = "The file could not be read:"
        errorText += e.Message + "\n"
        Return errorText
    End Try

End Function
```

PowerShell

```
    [CmdletBinding()]

   Param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
   [string]$District, 
   [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
   [string]$County,
   [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)] 
   [string]$FMS 

   )

Write-Host "District: $Dsistrict"
Write-Host "County: $County"
Write-Host "FMS: $FMS"
```

Comment: why are you calling **get-process**?

Answer (score 0):

These examples are in C#, but it's the same API.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/

More C# examples, but these are using the RunspaceFactory API you already have in your pipeline.
[Execute PowerShell Script from C# with Commandline Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527513/execute-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-with-commandline-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to PowerShell but may this help you

in your code

```
scriptParams.Parameters.Add("District", "D1")

scriptParams.Parameters.Add("County", "Lee")

scriptParams.Parameters.Add("FMS", "101000")

MyPipeline.Commands.Add(scriptParams)
```

I think this ADD new params to your script so value for already exit params not set

You need to pass param values to your script not add new param

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but there was no good answer and I just spent too long getting this to work to not share my knowledge.

In the VB code, you'd remove the following:

```
MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText)
MyPipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String")
```

Then, in place of the Out-String addition, add:

```
Dim myCommand As Command = New Command(scriptText, True)

' Add your parameters here.
' Obviously you can add variables instead of static strings if needed.
myCommand.Parameters.Add("District", "D1")
myCommand.Parameters.Add("County", "Lee")
myCommand.Parameters.Add("FMS", "101000")

' You can add switches in this manner as well. For example, a switch "I"
' You need to include the - with switches
myCommand.Parameters.Add("-i")

' Finally, apply your command object to the pipeline and proceed as normal    
MyPipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand)
```