# C# LAPS mslaps-encryptedpassword decryption

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, active-directory

I was wondering if there was an official C# way to get the LAPS password from `mslaps-encryptedpassword` attribute decrypted using C#?

I know you can use the below powershell module to get the password, but I am having trouble finding documentation on how to do it in C#.

Powershell:

`Get-LapsADPassword -Identity COMPUTERNAME -AsPlainText`

from lapspsh.dll

I can get the value in C#, but I am unsure how to decrypt it. Looking to do this natively in C# without invoking PowerShell script/module.

Edit: msLAPS-Password (cleartext password) is not set in the new April 2023 implementation of LAPS if you choose to encrypt the password

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute PowerShell Script from C# with Commandline Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527513/execute-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-with-commandline-arguments)

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface, however I am hoping to do it natively in C# without invoking a powershell module/script.

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft's [Windows LAPS schema extensions reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/laps/laps-technical-reference#mslaps-password), you can get the unencrypted password from the `msLAPS-Password` attribute:

> **msLAPS-Password**
>
> This attribute contains a Unicode string that specifies the clear-text version of the current password and other information.
>
> The data that's stored in this attribute is a JSON string that contains multiple name-value pairs. For example:
>
> `{"n":"Administrator","t":"1d8161b41c41cde","p":"A6a3#7%eb!57be4a4B95Z43394ba956de69e5d8975#$8a6d)4f82da6ad500HGx"}`
>
> Each name-value pair in the JSON string has a specific meaning:
>
> | Name | Value |
> | --- | --- |
> | "n" | Contains the name of the managed local administrator account |
> | "t" | Contains the UTC password update time represented as a 64-bit hexadecimal number |
> | "p" | Contains the clear-text password |

Comment: Thanks, however, msLAPS-Password is not set in the new April 2023 implementation of LAPS when you use an encrypted password.