# Running PowerShell from c# windows application passing boolean parameter

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm have a small launcher windows app in c# that runs powershell scripts.
They are being called as follow:

```
var ps1File = @"DBScripter.ps1";
var ticketname = this.txtTicketName.Text;
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "powershell.exe",
    Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -file \"{ps1File}\" -TicketName \"{ticketname}\"",
    UseShellExecute = false
};
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

This is working fine, but if I add a non-mandatory boolean param to the call like this:

```
var ps1File = @"DBScripter.ps1";
var ticketname = this.txtTicketName.Text;
bool release = true;
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "powershell.exe",
    Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -file \"{ps1File}\" -TicketName \"{ticketname}\" -IsProdRelease \"{release}\"",
    UseShellExecute = false
};
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

This does not work, whether I send a boolean, a string with $True or $true or an Integer with 1.

In the PS script, parameters are declared as follow:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$TicketName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$TicketPath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [boolean]$IsProdRelease
)
```

How should I pass this value from c# to the PS file execution?

Comment: You need $true instead of true.  Arguments are a string that gets translated to by the loader into an object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute PowerShell Script from C# with Commandline Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527513/execute-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-with-commandline-arguments)

Comment: You don't need to start `powershell.exe` you can execute it directly from C#

Answer (score 0):

As [jdweng mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76471644/running-powershell-from-c-sharp-windows-application-passing-boolean-parameter/76472389#comment134838628_76471644), the PowerShell equivalent of `true` is the special variable `$true`:

```
Arguments = $"... -IsProdRelease:${release}"
```

A better option is to type the script parameter as a `[switch]` instead of a `[boolean]` - this way you don't *need* an argument value, presence of the named parameter switch itself is enough:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "powershell.exe",
    Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -file \"{ps1File}\" -TicketName \"{ticketname}\"",
    UseShellExecute = false
};

if (release)
{
    startInfo.Arguments += " -IsProdRelease";
}
```

Binding a boolean literal (like in the example above) will also still work with `[switch]` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make it work!
I've changed the script to use the param as a string and pass 'true' as a string.

It works now.
Thank you all.